# Django L10N: Making the Flat Model of 'po' File Not Flat

Tags: django, localization, gettext

The problem is: .po files are flat. So, we don't have a convenient hierarchy.

Example:

```
msgid "SITE_TITLE"
msgstr "This is a title of my site"

msgid "ABOUT_SITE_TITLE"
msgstr "And now... about the site"
```

Problem occurs when we have a lot of messages in our .po file. It's difficult to find a specific message we want to change.

We also need to bind our .po messages to specific templates (html templates).

The obvious solution is to use custom prefix (for example as name of your template file). Then if we have home.html and about.html our message strings will be:

```
msgid "HOME:SITE_TITLE"
msgstr "This is a title of my site"

msgid "ABOUT:SITE_TITLE"
msgstr "And now... about the site"
```

Could you offer more convenient solution please?

Answer (score 1):

Basically .po files are ordinary text files with entries separated with an empty line. Writing a simple parser that will split one .po into multiple files based on prefix like `msgid "SOMETHING:` seems like a no-brainer solution for dealing with huge translation files. Organization into multiple po files simplifies the translation process (but you must keep the msgid unique, so the prefixes need to stay).

The next tool I recommend is called [django-rosetta](https://github.com/mbi/django-rosetta). It provides a web-based access to the po files, handles edition and displays occurrences of translation strings in files (i.e. templates).